# Open Foundation 6 Accordions for Med/Lg Screens Only

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, accordion

I'm attempting to use JS to automatically open a Foundation 6 accordion when the window size exceeds 640px. I've read a number of accordion-related posts on the Foundation forum and StackOverflow but still haven't been able to solve this issue.

Here's my latest code: http://codepen.io/rogetmone/pen/VaJNVw

```
$(document).foundation();
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth > 640) {
    $('#blackberry-recipes').addClass('is-active');
  }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a class of `is-active` doesn't affect the visibility of the content as you would've noticed. If you want to have the accordion section visible, you can `trigger` a `click` on the child link (`a`) of the `#blackberry-recipes` `div`:

```
$(document).foundation();
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth > 640) {
    console.log('hello');
    $('#blackberry-recipes > a').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

You can use the same principle for any other accordion item.

**[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/yassarikhan786/pen/dMxbRX)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!